# Calling a C++ DLL file in VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, dllimport

I need to use a C++ DLL file in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). Below is the [dumpbin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump) for the DLL file.

```
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>dumpbin /exports d:\dll\myssort.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Dump of file d:\dll\ myssort.dll
File Type: DLL
  Section contains the following exports for MySort.dll
    00000000 characteristics
    3D3F006E time date stamp Thu Jul 25 01:00:54 2002
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names
    ordinal hint RVA      name
          1    0 00001000 MySortA7
  Summary
        1000 .data
        1000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        3000 .text
```

Below is the function definition which is showing in the Visual Basic 6.0 Object Browser.

```
Function SortA7(udtArray As udtA7Rec, nTotalItems As Long) As Long
    Member of MySort. MySort
    Sort the elements of A7-type array
```

How do I call this method in VB.NET?

I tried doing a DLL import:

```
<DllImport("MySort.dll", _
SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Public Function SortA7(ByVal udtArray As MySort.udtA7Rec(), ByVal nTotalItems As Long) As Long
End Function
```

But it's giving me an error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: Vb.Net app and native C++ dll do not play together. You should write some wrapper in C++/CLI between to clue them together but looking how you formatted your question I suspect that you do not qualify.

Comment: +1 Because you don't deserve to be downvoted for being a newbie to interop and COM

Comment: Tried replacing Long with Integer, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

If it shows up in the Visual Basic 6.0 Object Browser, it is a [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) DLL. Use COM Interop. In [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET), go to *Project References*, go to the *COM* tab, and add the DLL file.

Comment: Strange, the dumpbin.exe output shows that it is *not* a COM server.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the response. 

There a .tlb file associated with this dll. In com tab its showing the reference to that tlb file. I added that reference. But the methord SortA7 is not comming up. When i type MySort. the intellisence is showwing only a sructure member.
I tried adding reference to the dll but its giving me the below error.

"A reference to 'D:\MySort.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

Comment: @HansPassant maybe the OP's VB6 is actually calling a *different* DLL from the one the OP thinks. The comment above also suggests the MySort.DLL is not a COM server. @ user Check the VB6 Object Browser to see what you are actually calling from the VB6